# Orgmode : do not switch to latex/MPS mode when entering math environment

Tags: org-mode, auctex

With a recent emacs-master and up-to-date packages, I noticed that the major mode of an org file switches from `org` mode to `latex/MPS` (as it appears on the modeline) whenever I enter in a math environment like `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`

Do you know how I can disable this switch and let the major mode be `org` mode when in math environments as it used to be?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior: when in `org` mode,  I am in `org` mode, regardless of whether I'm in a LaTeX equation environment or not. Do you run something like [polymode](https://github.com/polymode/polymode) that allows multiple major modes to coexist in a single buffer? If so, you might want to turn it off. Otherwise, can you reproduce with `emacs -q`? If not, your init file is at fault, so bisect it to figure out the culprit.

Comment: Yes, I use `polymode` and especially `poly-org` which happens to be the responsible for this issue. I finally got a fix [here](https://github.com/yangsheng6810/org-latex-impatient/issues/18#issuecomment-1498915596).